# Using util.parsing in Scala 2.11

Tags: eclipse, scala, import

I have written a Scala program with Eclipse Scala IDE that uses `scala.util.parsing.JSON` and I would like to transform it to support Scala 2.11 version. In Scala 2.11 I get an error: 
`error: object parsing is not a member of package util`. 
I have found out that the parsing library is not anymore in the util package by default, but has to be [downloaded separately here](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators).

I have downloaded that and tried to add it to my Eclipse project as a new source folder, but that didn't work out. The instructions are only for adding it to sbt, but I don't think that is relevant to me if I want to just use it in Eclipse.

Should I try to find a JAR file somewhere?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Should I try to find a JAR file somewhere?

Yes, you should. :)

And specifically, you should use this one (in SBT syntax):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.2"
```

The above line should be all you need to add to build.sbt if you're using SBT. If you want to manually add it to your project by downloading it, you can find it on [Maven Central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/1.0.2/).

The scala-parser-combinators library was removed in 2.11 so that people who don't use it don't have to pay a price for having it in the scala runtime library. Consequently, people who do want to use it have to now explicitly include it in their build. Note that the XML library was similarly removed in 2.11 to its own library.

Comment: Thanks! I added the jar file from the link you provided to Eclipse and added it to the build path. Then it started working.

Comment: You're welcome. You should check out sbt for your scala builds. Once you get used to it, its quite quick and flexible.

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this in IntelliJ14, using a plain project, not SBT? I'm reopening an intellij project on a different computer after the exact same (network) directory worked on a different one.

Comment: @cloudsurfin - what do you mean by a "plain project"? If you mean just using IntelliJ 14's project, you'll need to open the module structure and add an external library with the corresponding maven details.